# How can I create the illusion of movement with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, effects, blur

I am using GIMP to edit my images.  I have a regular playing card from a top down, 2D view.  I want it to appear as though it were being tossed very quickly.  I wanted to remove the top down view and add some speed blur.  I have checked many of GIMP's features, but cannot find what I am looking for.  Any help or similar suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want a [**Motion Blur**](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-mblur.html):

> You can find this filter in the image menu under **Filters** → **Blur** → ***Motion Blur***

[image]
<sup>Playing card image courtesy of [Byron Knoll](http://byronknoll.blogspot.com/2011/03/vector-playing-cards.html)</sup>